# Convert SSD to pre calculated result set

Tags: c#

I develop a software where complex logarithmic computations are used. 1 TB SSDs are now available. Is it possible to store pre calculated result set in SSD where the memory address will be the parameter to pull the result.

For example I have a function with parameter x,y,z. f(x,y,z) = result. x,y,z will be between 0 and 10000. I want to store the result in memory location x*1000000 + y*1000 + z.

What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: When x <= 10,000 then this has at most 10G elements. Nut unfeasible to keep in memory.

Comment: Use a memory-mapped file.

Comment: Henk Holterman I wanted to keep it in the SSD. Permanently to help speed up computation.

Comment: A simple file then. FileStream.Position will do what you want.